# RenderPartial ignoring a surrounding Knockout foreach

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I am trying to render an interactive tree with a combination of ASP.net, knockout, and javascript. Each node in the tree has a list of 'items' and a list of 'groups', where each 'group' is another node. Here is the HTML for each node in its simplest form (this is _GroupView.cshtml, so it is recursive):

```
<div>
    <ul id="siblingList" data-bind="foreach: childItems">
        <li>
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ItemView"); }
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="groupList" data-bind="foreach: childGroups">
        <li>
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_GroupView"); }
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <button data-bind="click: addItem">+ Item</button>
    <button data-bind="click: addGroup">+ Group</button>
</div>
```

AddItem and addGroup add new javascript view models to the childItems and childGroups lists that should then be bound to the views created by RenderPartial via the foreach binding. This works perfectly for the items, but there are problems with the groups.

I am seeing an issue where this page, on load, is ignoring the knockout foreach and the RenderPartials are always being called even though the childItems and childGroups lists are empty. This results in infinite recursion of the _GroupViews and a StackOverflowException.

Why is the foreach being ignored? Is RenderPartial always going to be called once even if it is inside of a conditional expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `RenderPartial` statements will always be called, because these are expanded at the server side. The knockout `foreach` is processed on the client side.

Maybe you can use a template inside the `foreach` loops: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html ([note 2](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-2-using-the-foreach-option-with-a-named-template))